# Django Foreign Key Model Error

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I Created Two models "**Restaurantmenu**" and "**Cart**", Where Restaurantmenu.Product_id is Primary key and Cart.prdct_id is Foreign key.
Migration is done without any error. But when I insert data in the Cart then I got an error:

ValueError: Cannot assign "'4359197'": "Cart.prdct_id" must be a "Restaurantmenu" instance.

Find the Model File:

```
class Restaurantmenu(models.Model):
   product_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
   shopid = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   prod_type = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
   prd_category = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
   prd_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
   prd_amt = models.FloatField(null=True)
   prod_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
   offer = models.FloatField(null=True,default=0)
   offer_type= models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,default='None')
  status = models.BooleanField(default=1)
  image = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.product_id

class Cart(models.Model):
  cart_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
  cust_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
  prdct_id = models.ForeignKey(Restaurantmenu,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
  no_of_quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True)
  total_amt = models.FloatField(null=True)
  status = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
  created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.cart_id
```

Its REST API View:

```
def addcart(self,requestobj,cart_amt):
    cartid = self.generate_cart_id(7)
    print(type(int(requestobj['pid'])))
    try:
        cartobj,cartcreate = Cart.objects.get_or_create(
                cart_id = cartid,
                cust_id = requestobj['Userid'],
                prdct_id= int(requestobj['pid']),
                defaults={
                    'no_of_quantity':requestobj['quantity'],
                    'total_amt': cart_amt,
                    'status':'Pending'
                }
            )
        if cartcreate:
            response = {"Status":"Success","Message":"Added to the cart","code":"200"}
        else:
            response = {"Status":"Error","Message":"Not Added, Try Again","code":"100"}
    except MultipleObjectsReturned:
        response =  {"Status":"Error","Message":"Cart Already Exist","code":"100"}
    return response 

def generate_cart_id(self,len):
    cartid = ""
    for i in range(len):
        rnd_nbr = str(random.randint(1,9))
        cartid+=str(rnd_nbr)
    return cartid
```

Comment: Can you post view or serializer where you are trying to create Cart?

Comment: Its a Rest API:

Comment: please edit the answer and include your comment code.

Comment: what return the method **self.generate_cart_id(7)** a object or a integer?

Comment: def addcart(self,requestobj,cart_amt):
  cartid = self.generate_cart_id(7)
   cartobj,cartcreate = Cart.objects.get_or_create(
     cart_id = cartid,
     cust_id = requestobj['Userid'],
     prdct_id= int(requestobj['pid']),
     defaults={
      'no_of_quantity':requestobj['quantity'],
      'total_amt': cart_amt,
      'status':'Pending'
     }
    )

Comment: @Gytree def generate_cart_id(self,len):
  cartid = ""
  for i in range(len):
   rnd_nbr = str(random.randint(1,9))
   cartid+=str(rnd_nbr)
  return cartid

Comment: Your foreign key is typically *not* something that ends with `_id`.

Comment: Stop putting the code in comments. Edit your question and put the code there, properly formatted.

Comment: It return a string @G

Comment: @AbhishekKumar update the answer don't put code in comments.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar: [edit] your question.

Comment: Your `__unicode__` functions furthermore already violate a contract: these should return strings.

Comment: @Gytree  i update my view

Answer (score 0):

You have prdct_id set as a foreign key, which uses the ID in the database, but the Django ORM is expecting an instance of `Restaurantmenu`.

So, you may need to add something like:

```
menu = Restaurantmenu.objects.get(product_id = int(requestobj['pid']))
```

to get the reference to that menu object,

And then in your get_or_create, use it like this:

```
cartobj,cartcreate = Cart.objects.get_or_create(
                cart_id = cartid,
                cust_id = requestobj['Userid'],
                prdct_id= menu,
                defaults={
                    'no_of_quantity':requestobj['quantity'],
                    'total_amt': cart_amt,
                    'status':'Pending'
                }
            )
```

Comment: thnks a lot it resolved and thnks for explanation also

Comment: Great, glad I could help! Feel free to accept this answer if it solved everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a foreign key to your model django include the 'field'_id in the databese table. for example in yours models

```
class Menu(Model):
    pass

class Cart(Model):
    menu = ForeignKey(Menu, CASCADE)
```

django add two properties in your **cart** model instances, **menu** which is a Menu instance, and **menu_id** which is a integer that contains the menu instance id. django also include a **cart_set** property in the Menu instances.

in order to add one cart to a menu i need to add a new cart and set the menu, but for use the menu property django expect a Menu instance not the id or pk

```
mi_menu = Menu.objects.create()
cart = Cart.objects.create(menu=mi_menu)
```

if you want to use the primary key you need to use the menu_id added for django for example

```
mi_menu = Menu.objects.create()
cart = Cart.objects.create(menu_id=mi_menu.pk)
```

you must be sure that the menu id exists in the db.

**in your code you tray to create the related object with the id but django expect a model instance.**